# New LinkedIn Permissions Problems (Rails omniauth-linkedin gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm using the omniauth-linkedin gem for my rails application:

https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin

It should be taking into account new LinkedIn permissions request procedures and scopes, but I am not having success obtaining either email addresses or full profiles (anything other than the default profile overviews).

Here is my omniauth.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'], :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress'
end
```

The full profile and email address request are going through to LinkedIn initially, before the user enters her/his credentials. However, the scope requests are lost once the user signs in, and only the default profile overview information is accessible.

I think my problem has something to do with having to specifically request those fields within the scopes that I want, as is mentioned on the gem page (https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin). Still, I have tried adding specific field requests to my omniauth.rb file with no success (email field request below):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'], :scope => 'r_fullprofile+r_emailaddress',
  :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "location", "positions", "educations"]
end
```

Apparently, I am supposed to request the default fields of the profile overview in addition to the non-default fields like email-address, positions, and educations in order to access these latter non-default fields.

LinkedIn email-address should be straightforward, as it is not a structured object like positions or educations are, and I believe I am missing code for specific fields within positions and educations that I want (not sure how i would write that and would love some input on that as well). I am using my new API keys, so I'm not sure what the problem may be. Do I need some kind of special permission from LinkedIn? Help is appreciated! Thank you.

Also, here is the relevant code for my auth controller:

```
require 'linkedin'

class AuthController < ApplicationController

  def auth
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'])

    request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => 
                                      "http://#{request.host_with_port}/callback")

    session[:rtoken] = request_token.token
    session[:rsecret] = request_token.secret

    redirect_to client.request_token.authorize_url
  end

  def callback

    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'])

    if current_user.atoken.nil? && current_user.asecret.nil?
      pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
      atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)
      current_user.atoken = atoken
      current_user.asecret = asecret
      current_user.uid = client.profile(:fields => ["id"]).id
      flash.now[:success] = 'Signed in with LinkedIn.'
    elsif current_user.atoken && current_user.asecret 
      client.authorize_from_access(current_user.atoken, current_user.asecret)
      flash.now[:success] = 'Signed in with LinkedIn.'
    end
```

Comment: Did you get a new application API key? Only those issued after the new permissions scoping functionality was launched are able to trigger it.

Comment: there seems to be something funny happening with the new api permissions...others are reporting similar problems

Comment: I had to request a new API key/secret for the new permissions stuff to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but this worked for me

I just added the config with the scope passed in the request_token_path

```
LINKEDIN_CONFIGURATION = { :site => 'https://api.linkedin.com',
:authorize_path => '/uas/oauth/authenticate',
:request_token_path =>'/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+r_network+r_contactinfo',
:access_token_path => '/uas/oauth/accessToken' }

client = LinkedIn::Client.new(LINKEDIN_API_KEY, LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY, LINKEDIN_CONFIGURATION )
```

and the rest of the code is the same.

Be sure to change the client constructor in the callback method as well.

Comment: +1, Good answer.. I was trying `{:request_token_path =>'/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+r_network+r_contactinfo'}` as 3rd parameter in LinkedIn::Client initialization can you explain why it was not working for me?

Comment: Not quite sure because I'm not sure how it works on the Linkedin side. By passing just the request_toeken_path you are assuming that the other 3 parameter are already set that way by default. I modified this code directly from the linked in site so maybe there's a reason why they have you pass in all 4 params in the hash.